# Axiomatic Bargaining: Nash's Solution

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

The following text is from the book: **Bargaining and Markets** by **Osborne and Rubinstein**, **Academic Press Inc**.

**Page 17** under the chapter **The Axiomatic Approach: Nash's Solutions:**.

> Two individuals can divide a dollar in any way they wish. If they fail
>   to agree on a division, the dollar is forfeited. The individuals may,
>   if they wish, discard some of the dollar.   In terms of our model, we
>   have   $A = \{(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb R^2: a_1 + a_2 \le 1$ and $a_i
> > \ge 0$ for $i = 1, 2\}$  (all possible divisions of the dollar), and 
>   $D = (0, 0)$ (neither player receives any payoff in the event of
>   disagreement).   Each player is concerned only about the share of the
>   dollar he receives: Player $i$ prefers $a \in A$ to $b \in A$ if and
>   only if $a_i \gt b_i (i = 1, 2)$.
>   **Thus, Player $i’s$ preferences over lotteries on $A$ can be represented by the *expected value* of a utility function $u_i$ with
>   domain $[0, 1]$**.

**My question:** In the last line what good does it serve by using *"expected value"* in  the line:

> expected value of the utility function $u_i$ with domain $[0,1]$

Instead, what will we lose if we just write: "...represented by the utility function $u_i$ with domain $[0, 1]$."$?$ (i.e we drop expected value)

***EDIT 1:***

**(added after reading @Shane 's answer)**
In the above question

> Set $A = \{(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb R^2: a_1 + a_2 \le 1$ and $a_i  \ge 0$
>   for $i = 1, 2\}$,    $D=(0,0) \in A$, $D$ is the *disagreement event*.
>   For each Player $i$ there is a function $u_i:A \cup \{D\} \to \mathbb R$
>   , called a utility function, such that one lottery is preferred to
>   another if and only if the *expected utility of the first exceeds that
>   of the second*.

Here I am not able to visualize a lottery $L$ as is mentioned in the answer by @Shane. What will this lottery look like? When calculating the expected value, which all elements of $A$ will we take into consideration (since $A$ is a non denumerable infinite set)?

PS: It is taken from the famous, **Nash's Axiomatic Bargaining Theory**.

***EDIT 2:***
@Shane

I know about vNM utility theorem. The problem is, I am not able to apply it here. Here $A = \{(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb R^2: a_1 + a_2 \le 1$ and $a_i  \ge 0 \}$. So $A$ has infinite elements. A typical $A$ would look like $\{(0.1,0.9),(0.2,0.4),(0.5,0.1),(0,0)...\}$. It will have infinite elements. In this particular example let us call $p=(0.1,0.9),q=(0.2,0.4),r=(0.5,0.1),s=(0,0)$. So for Agent $1$, $r\succ q \succ p \succ s $ since $r_1\gt q_1 \gt p_1 \gt s_1$. (If choosing among the above four alternatives only).

Here, Nash says that

> each player's preference be defined on a set of lotteries over
>   **possible** agreements and not just on the set of agreements themselves.

Further:

> one lottery is preferred to another if and only if the *expected
>   utility of the first exceeds that of the second*.

Let us say that $u_i(a)=a_i$ where $a \in A$ and $i=1,2$

So if I try to construct a lottery ,
 say $L=t_1 \cdot p+t_2\cdot q+t_3\cdot r+t_4\cdot s$ where $\Sigma t_i = 1$ and $M=x_1\cdot p+x_2\cdot q+x_3\cdot r+x_4\cdot s$ where $\Sigma x_i = 1$ and $p,q,r,s \in A$.
By vNM, for agent 1, $L \succ M$ iff $t_1u_1(p)+t_2u_1(q)+t_3u_1(r)+t_4u_1(s) \gt x_1u_1(p)+x_2u_1(q)+x_3u_1(r)+x_4u_1(s)$
OR, $t_1p_1+t_2q_1+t_3r_1+t_4s_1 \gt x_1p_1+x_2q_1+x_3r_1+x_4s_1$

Right?

**My doubts:**
here I just picked up $4$ elements of $A$. But there are infinite such elements in $A$. So how will I come up with a lottery? I mean we will not get such $t_i $ or $x_i $ such that $\Sigma t_i = 1$ or $\Sigma x_i = 1$.

**EDIT 3**

Our agreement set is as usual $A=\{a_1, a_2, a_3 \cdot \cdot \cdot\}$ where $a_k$s are various agreements over which the two agents can reach. If the two agents do not reach to an agreement then disagreement event $D=(d_1,d_2)$ is invoked. Let a general element of the set $A$ be denoted by $a$.
**For example** in the case of our “splitting the dollar game” the agreement set, $A = \{(a_1, a_2) \in \mathbb R^2: a_1 + a_2 \le 1$ and $a_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1, 2\}$. Here $D=(0,0)$

Now the text (in the above mentioned book) says:

> Denote by $p \cdot  a$ the lottery in which the agreement $a \in A$ is
>   reached with probability $ p \in [0, 1]$  and the disagreement event $D= (d_1,d_2)$
>    occurs with probability $1 – p$. Let $\succcurlyeq _i$ be Player $i’$s preference ordering over lotteries of the form $p \cdot a$, and
>   let $\succ _i$ denote strict preference. Consider an agreement $a^*$
>   with the property that for $(i, j) = (1, 2)$ and $(i, j) = (2, 1)$, for
>   every $a \in A$ and $p \in [0, 1]$ for which $p \cdot a \succ_i a^*$
>   we have $p \cdot a^* \succcurlyeq_j a$.

**My doubt** is how can we construct a lottery like $p \cdot a$ where sum of probabilities is *not equal* to 1. Should not it(the lottery) be something like $p \cdot a + (1-p) \cdot D$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The key is that player $i$ has preferences over lotteries, not just the outcomes themselves. Technically speaking, we want to know not only $u(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$, but also $u(L)$ where $L$ is a lottery. One example is that $L$ could be a lottery with a 50% probability on $0$ and a 50% probability on $1$. As for why they want to allow for lotteries here, I can't say as I don't have the textbook in front of me right now. But, generally speaking, we do that in game theory just to allow for the possibilities of mixed actions and mixed Nash equilibria. If this is still unclear, please post a comment below and I can try to amend my answer to clarify further.

By the way, I teach game theory, and I personally probably wouldn't take credit off if you didn't mention *expected* there on an exam, unless that was specifically the point of the question. So you're right to think it's a somewhat nuanced, and not necessarily that motivated, inclusion.

Comment: Thanx.
I have edited my question after reading your answer. My doubts are in the edited(appended) part.

Comment: Hi Amy. Are you familiar with the [von Neumann-Morgenstern utility theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Morgenstern_utility_theorem)? It's that theorem that allows us to compare lotteries if we have a given $u$. So what you have in the original question is the $u$ to compare deterministic outcomes and then you can compare lotteries over those outcomes by appealing to von Neumann-Morgenstern (vNM). In terms of what good that serves, all I can think of is that you want to be able to bargain over probabilistic events, not just deterministic ones.

Comment: hey. Thanx.  I could not fit in my problem in the comment box. So I have edited (appended) my original question with my doubts. Please read **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Thanks for adding detail. The statement after the OR there is incorrect, or at least doesn't follow from the previous statement. Suppose $u(x)=x^2$. Then let $p$ be a lottery with equal probabilities on $0$ and $10$. Let $q$ be a deterministic lottery that pays $6$ no matter what (i.e. with probability 1). Then $p\succ q$ because $\frac{1}{2}100 + \frac{1}{2}0 > 36$ even though the expected value of the lottery $q$, 6, is greater than that from $p$, 5, here, so your statement after the OR would fail here. Here it's because the agent is risk-loving (has that squared utility function).

Comment: I had already defined my utility function above. It was $u_i(a)=a_i$ where $a \in A$ and $i=1,2$. That is why I replaced $u_1(p)$ with $p_1$. I got what what you are trying to say in your above comment. But my main doubt was, how to use vNM in this particular question? Please refer to the last two lines of my original question (the last two lines of the **EDIT 2** part).

Comment: The lotteries can be over a finite subset of $A$, as you have. If you want to think what a lottery looks like over infinitely many possible outcomes, you can think of it as a probabilility density function, so that the probabilities integrate to 1 rather than sum to 1.

Comment: Thanx a lot. There is one more doubt with respect to construction of vNM lotteries. I have added that as **EDIT 3** in my original post (question).

Comment: Yeah - I agree with you. I'm guessing they're just going forward with $d_1=d_2=0$, and that's why the $(1-p)D$ is dropping out.